# Adding on a column with different where clauses using a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I've got a query that pulls data from the current year, and I'm trying to add on data in a new column from the previous year using a subquery since the main query's WHERE statement limits it to the current year. I keep getting a an error that the subquery returns more than 1 value, but when I run just the subquery, it's only one value per ID.  I previously was running these 2 queries separately and using vlookup in Excel to join the final column, but I'd love a way to do this in one query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_master.id_num,  stud_term_sum_div_a.trm_gpa,  
       (SELECT stud_term_sum_div_b.trm_gpa  
        FROM student_master LEFT OUTER JOIN
             stud_term_sum_div stud_term_sum_div_b
             ON student_master.id_num = stud_term_sum_div_b.id_num 
        WHERE ( stud_term_sum_div_b.yr_cde = '2018'
       ) A AS Prev_GPA
FROM student_master LEFT OUTER JOIN
     stud_term_sum_div stud_term_sum_div_a
     ON student_master.id_num = stud_term_sum_div_a.id_num
WHERE stud_term_sum_div_a..yr_cde = '2019'
```

I expect there to be 3 columns - student ID, 2019 gpa, 2018 gpa

Comment: Change your date range to include both years and then use `CASE` statements to determine which years data goes into what column.

Answer (score 0):

To get the specific years you mentioned in your question, you could do something like this, using Case statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_master.id_num, 
    Case when stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde = '2018' then stud_term_sum_div.trm_gpa end as '2018 GPA',  
    Case when stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde = '2019' then stud_term_sum_div.trm_gpa end as '2019 GPA'
FROM student_master LEFT OUTER JOIN
     stud_term_sum_div 
     ON student_master.id_num = stud_term_sum_div.id_num
WHERE stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde in ('2018','2019')
```

To get this year and last year without using specific dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_master.id_num, 
    Case when CAST(stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde as int) = year(getdate())-1 then stud_term_sum_div.trm_gpa end as 'Last GPA',  
    Case when CAST(stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde as int) = year(getdate()) then stud_term_sum_div.trm_gpa end as 'Current GPA'
FROM student_master LEFT OUTER JOIN
     stud_term_sum_div 
     ON student_master.id_num = stud_term_sum_div.id_num
WHERE CAST(stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde as int) >= year(getdate())-1
```